# The terminal is printing even though there is no function telling it to

Tags: for-loop, terminal, atom-editor

I'am trying to print a 2-D matrix but when I finish inputing the terminal starts printing the first input indefinitely. I initialized a, b, i and j thinking they were causing the problem since this has happened before and doing that fixed it but it's not working in this case. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  int a = 100;
  int b = 100;
  int d;
  int i = 500;
  int j = 500;
  int c[i][j];
  int Interation;

  printf("\n");

  printf("Please enter the number of rows: \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Please enter the number of columns: \n");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  Interation = a*b;
  
  printf("Enter Matrix A \n");
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
        scanf(" %d", &(c[i][j]));
      }
  }
 i = 0;
 j = 0;
  for (d = 0;d < Interation; d++){
    while (i < a){
    printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
   }
   j += 1;
   i = 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Terminal:

```
Please enter the number of rows: 
2
Please enter the number of columns: 
2
Enter Matrix A 
1
7
39
9
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: there's a `printf` inside the bottom `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `i` within your `while` loop, otherwise `i<a` will be true forever (hence the infinite loop)

```
while (i < a){
  printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
  i++;
}
```